# Leave or Leaves?

Tags: present-simple

> Lucy has just entered date roulette. Meet her before she leaves!

is this sentence correct? especially do I need to write "leave" or "leaves" ?

Comment: Why would you choose either "leave" or "leaves"? Please explain your understanding.

Comment: @virolino i don't know the difference, just sound better with leaves but i m probably completely wrong ... the message is a notification

Comment: Yes, the message is a notification. Did you try to analyze the grammar of the sentence? That will help a lot.

Comment: Hi Loki, welcome to ELL. We expect people to do a bit of research before asking a question. In this case, you could have a look at an online article like this one: https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/simple-present/. If this doesn't explain everything, please edit your question to provide  more information about what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @virolino i m very bad in english :( this why I come here to understand .. but i don't understand do i write something wrong ? when we must write leave and when we must write leaveS ?

Comment: You can use a resource like [this](https://www.curso-ingles.com/en/resources/conjugator/leave): *I leave / she leaves*.